# Table right border (bootstrap + custom css)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 2.3 version and some custom CSS styles. I got next problem: when I try to add right border to the last td in row it is not displayed. But it is displayed when I zoom browser window, or if I set width to 2px. I use chrome but it seems like in firefox there is the same issue.

Jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ct7dC/

CSS:

```
    table.entity-table > tbody > tr > td:last-child {
        border-right: 1px solid #DDD; /* It works only if I set 2px width. Also works with 1px width but if I zoom browser window */
    }
```

Also noticed that when I zoom the page table left and right borders become not straight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the border-right not being smooth is duo the th ontop of it has no extra width from the border(it simply has no border), because the row has gaint some extra width because the border-right is no inline border. You can fix this by ginving the th also a border.

```
table.entity-table > thead > tr > th 
{
    background-color: #DDD;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ct7dC/5/)**

Now for the Ubuntu problem. I don't know if you use a variant of chrome(like chromium)?

**Edit**

The fiddle also works on chromium windows, so certainly has to do something width ubuntu.

Comment: The reason why I don't add border to table itself because I also implemented table row selection - when I select a row (by clicking on it) I expand the row (actually show another hidden row) and show some info. But the expanded row must have other border. when I set this border I get 2px width: one from table and one from row. I hope you got what I mean, hard to put it in jsfiddle

Comment: Could you provide a little html example, because the border that shouldn't work(only when 2px), actually just works fine for me.

Comment: Does it work in my jsfiddle example? It doesn't work in my browser http://jsfiddle.net/Ct7dC/

Comment: Yes i can see the border-right. Look if something is blocking the border right. Btw i'm also using chrome.

Comment: Check my update, hope that is what you mean with not 'straight'.

Comment: Well, now it works both on ubuntu and windows. Although I have some issues with borders when I dynamically expand table rows, but hopefully will figure it out. Thanks a million !

Answer (score 0):

Like this
**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ct7dC/1/)**

**css**

```
table.entity-table > tbody > tr > td {
    vertical-align: middle;
border-left: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

Comment: what's the difference?